# Sql Query to order data sorted by ranking but multiplied by how long ago it was published

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a feed of articles which are currently ranked by "votes" in the SQL query. I would like to factor in the amount of time since it was published in order to give more weight to recent articles.

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles 
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
ORDER BY (votes * (720/#####)) DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

What can I put into place of "#####" to return the amount of time (in minutes) since the article was published?

Therefore, an article with a vote of 1 that was published 10 minutes ago, would equal 72 (1 * 720/10) ...
and rank below an article with a vote of 10 but published 60 minutes ago, equaling 120 (10 * 720/60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `date` is the published day, you can use [`timestampdiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles 
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
ORDER BY votes * (720/TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, date, NOW())) DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: when attempting this, I get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC LIMIT 100' at line 1

Comment: I see it now. Need one more parentheses before "DESC". Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @banjax . . . Or one less before.  I removed the first open paren.